# How to publish localdb to Azure from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: database, visual-studio-2017, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, publish

When Publishing my Website to Microsoft Azure using Visual Studio 2017, the Publish wizard does not detect that there are any Databases to publish.

[image]

The Website publishes ok, but with no database to connect to the published site errors.

I've tried with Automatic Migrations Enabled and Disabled.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BB.Models.BetterBusesDb>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        ContextKey = "BB.Models.BetterBusesDb";
    }
```

How do I get the Publish Mechanism to detect that there is a Database to Publish ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a Azure SQL Database created where you would be publishing the DB. You can follow this article to [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) the DB

Comment: Didn't exactly answer my question, but did give me the clue I needed!.  Frustratingly, even when rectified, the publish dialog box continued to state "No Databases are selected to publish", even though the database was published!

Comment: Can you try logging out from Visual Studio and logging in again? It will pick the recent changes from your Azure account.